# Why does usb_control_msg take 0.25 second to complete

Tags: kernel, usb, usb-device

I am sending a synchronous control message to a USB device with the call `usb_control_msg`. It is taking .25 second to complete. Is it normal/expected? The USB port is USB 3.0. The device is a Cypress FX3 module. The similar test done a Windows system (same port, device, FX3 firmware) returns every message in much less time. With Linux, I noticed that the first message sent takes 10 microseconds to complete, than the next 19 or so will take 0.25 second to complete. Than there is another message that will complete quickly followed by another 19 or so messages that will be slow. Also, I cannot send control messages with setup data longer than 8 bytes. I am going to try to implement asynchronous messages, but it would still be good to know if this behaviour can be improved for synchronous calls.

```
ktime_t start_time = ktime_get();
int ret = usb_control_msg(device, usb_sndctrlpipe(device, 0), 0, 0x40, 0, 0, &command_data_payload, 8, 5000);

if (ret < 0)
   printk(KERN_ERR "Messaged failed: %d\n", ret);
else
   printk("message took: %llu\n", ktime_get() - message_start_time);
```

Correction: i do not know if the Windows app I used in the comparison uses sync or async calls. I will definitely try to implement the test with async calls.

Update: Using async calls, the messages are sent out much quicker, but it still takes 0.25 second for the completion callback to be called. For 20 messages sent out sequentially, 1 completed in very little time and the others each took 0.25 seconds. Maybe the delay is a function of the FX3 USB device module. Also, on closer inspection on Windows, the messages also mostly take 0.25 second each to complete, with a few which complete more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to guess that because async messages sent out sequentially, go out quickly but the completion callback and the responses from the USB device still take 0.25 second to occur, that the delay was because of the Cypress FX3 module. I am also including the code for the async messages.

```
static struct usb_ctrlrequest ctrl_request;
static ktime_t last_time = 0;

static void write_control_callback(struct urb *urb)
{
   ktime_t now_time = ktime_get();
   if (last_time != 0)
       printk("skel_write_bulk_callback: %llu\n", now_time - last_time);
   last_time = now_time;
}

static long send_command(uint8_t * command_data_payload)
{
   int ret;
   struct urb * cUrb;
   void * buf;

   cUrb = usb_alloc_urb(0, GFP_KERNEL);
   if (!cUrb)
      return 1;

   buf = usb_alloc_coherent(device, 32, GFP_KERNEL, &cUrb->transfer_dma);
   if (!buf)
      return 1;

   memcpy(buf, command_data_payload, 32);  

   ctrl_request.bRequest = 0;
   ctrl_request.bRequestType = 0x40;
   ctrl_request.wValue = 0;
   ctrl_request.wIndex = 0;
   ctrl_request.wLength = 32;

   usb_fill_control_urb(cUrb, device, usb_sndctrlpipe(device, 0), (unsigned char*)(&ctrl_request),
buf, 32, skel_write_bulk_callback, NULL);

   ret = usb_submit_urb(cUrb, GFP_KERNEL);
   if (ret)
      printk("could not submit urb\n");
}
```

Warning!!!: I do not release the allocated buffer correctly in this code.